# Hair particles will not appear on specific faces?

Tags: modeling, mesh, particles, hair

I wonder why when I try to add hair particles to a specific face, it wouldn't add. Is there a way to make it work?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to click **Use modifier stack** in particles settings:

[image]

Comment: Oh, thanks. Well I'm glad that was something simple.